# How remove gray line on top UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Init UIViewController code:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGSize boundsSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    CGRect rectTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, boundsSize.width, boundsSize.height - 64);
    UITableView* contentTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rectTableViewFrame];

    contentTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    contentTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    contentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Next add in UITableView custom view (header):

```
    CustomView* customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
    CGRect customViewFrame = customView.frame;
    customViewFrame.origin.y = - customView.size.height;
    customView.frame = customViewFrame;

    contentTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, customViewFrame.origin.y);
    contentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(customViewFrame.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
    [contentTableView addSubview: customView];
```

Problem: When scroll contentTableView the top customView there is a gray line... How delete this?
I don't use methods:

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

But if use simple view with white background color there is no line.

Comment: try to comment contentInset line and check once.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set no-line style like:

```
contentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

and add a gray line at the bottom of you `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I used (look to top):                                      contentTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
contentTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
contentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: Because UINavigationController has 1px(0.5px in retina) shadow line, and the 1px(0.5px in retina) gray line of UITableViewCell is at point(0, 0). In stationary status, the navigation shadow hides the cell gray line, but actually the gray line exists.

Comment: `[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];` deleted navBar shadow. but did not help...

Comment: The problem is not due to the navigation, but the gray top line which at point(0, 0) on UITableViewCell. You can try to set `UITableView.separatorInset` and `UITableViewCell.separatorInset`.

Comment: Not work... tried UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0); and UIEdgeInsetsZero

Comment: delete `for (UIView* view in [contentTableView subviews])`